# Problem with basis of endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The problem is

Let $\phi$  be an endomorphism of a $n$- dimensional vector space V. Suppose that $\phi$ has n different eigenvalues. Prove that exists a vector $v$ of $V$ such $\{v,\phi(v), . . . , \phi^{n-1}(v)\}$ is a basis of $V$.

I tried to prove it by induction. But after proving it to be true for 1 vector, I can't figure out the way to proceed.
How would you prove this?

Answer (score 1):

As $\phi$ has $n$ different eigenvalues. We can assume that we have $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$, $n$ eigenvectors which are each associated to one and only one eigenvalue.

Then consider the vector $v=e_1+e_2+...+e_n$

To show that ${v,\phi(v),\dots,\phi^{n−1}(v)}$ is a basis of $V$, use a vandermonde matrix or Lagrange polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\varphi$ has n distinct eigenvalues, the characteristic polynomial of $\varphi$ splits completely. Its minimal polynomial have the same irreducibles as the characteristic polynomial, so we may write $f(x)=\min_{\varphi}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-c_i)$ with $c_i$ being the eigenvalues of $\varphi$. We may expand the product to get $f(x)$ in the form of $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$.

For any $v\in V,f(\varphi)v=0$. Since the eigenvectors $v_i$ of $\varphi$ are linearly independent and $\dim V=n$, we may write $v=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i v_i$. Then $\varphi^k(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ic_i^kv_i$ and thus, take $v\ne 0$,$\beta_0v+\beta_1\varphi(v)+...+\beta_{n-1}\varphi^{n-1}(v)=0 \iff \beta
_j=0 \;\forall j$. Hence $\{v,\phi(v), . . . , \phi^{n-1}(v)\}$ is a basis of V.